# How many straight lines can be made between 10 points such that 4 of them are colinear?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, permutations, combinations

So i know how to get the answer. We just have to find $C(10,2)$ and subtract $C(4,2)$ and add 1.

We are basically counting all the points between co-linear points as 1.

So the question is why we are doing that.

Lets consider 4 points to be $A,B,C,D$ and the lines that could be made from them are $AB,BC,CD,DA,AC,BD$.

Clearly these lines are different from each other unless it is specified that distance between them are equal.

So Why we are counting all of them as 1 ? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: I think that by "line" the question means a line which is infinite in both directions. So if $A,B,C$ are collinear, then the lines $AB,BC,CA$ are identical.

Comment: yes that might be the case. Can you tell me how to close this question.

Comment: You mean not lines, but probably line segments. $ ^9 C_4 ?$

Comment: sorry i got confused between lines and line segments. alamgest answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assume that there are no lines through more than 2 points except for the line $L$ containing the 4. So for each of the points on $L$ we have 6 lines to the other points. That is 24 lines plus $L$, giving 25. We then have lines between the other 6 points. There are ${6\choose 2}=15$ pairs of points each of which gives a line, so a grand total of 40. As a check note that there are ${10\choose 2}=45$ pairs of points in all. But ${4\choose 2}=6$ give the same line $L$, in other words 5 duplicates, so a total of $45-5=40$ distinct lines.